# Spark Column merging all list into 1 single list

Tags: pyspark

I want the below column to merge into a single list for n-gram calculation. I am not sure how can I merge all the lists in a column into a single one.

```
+--------------------+
|              author|
+--------------------+
|       [Justin, Lee]|
|[Chatbots, were, ...|
|[Our, hopes, were...|
|[And, why, wouldn...|
|[At, the, Mobile,...|
+--------------------+
```

(Edit)Some more info:
I would like this as a spark df column and all the words including the repeated ones in a single list. The data is kind of big so I want to try avoiding methods like collect

Comment: Do you want to retain the information as a Spark DataFrame? Is the DataFrame only a couple of rows long, like in your example? Do you want to retain duplicate words? Please provide more information.

Comment: Okay updated the question with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP wants to aggregate all the arrays/lists into the top row.

```
values = [(['Justin','Lee'],),(['Chatbots','were'],),(['Our','hopes','were'],),
          (['And','why','wouldn'],),(['At','the','Mobile'],)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['author',])
df.show()
+------------------+
|            author|
+------------------+
|     [Justin, Lee]|
|  [Chatbots, were]|
|[Our, hopes, were]|
|[And, why, wouldn]|
| [At, the, Mobile]|
+------------------+
```

This step suffices.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.groupby().agg(F.collect_list('author').alias('list_of_authors'))
df.show(truncate=False)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|list_of_authors                                                                                                                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray(Justin, Lee), WrappedArray(Chatbots, were), WrappedArray(Our, hopes, were), WrappedArray(And, why, wouldn), WrappedArray(At, the, Mobile)]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: you forgot to put that list back to spark dataframe column . Also lot of lines of code and iterations make it complex

Comment: My understanding was that he wants to have a python list, or am I mistaken?

Comment: i guess he himself will be able to clarify further ,also its not advised to use collect until you know surely that machine won't run out of driver memory

Comment: No not a python list a spark dataframe column
But you are using "collect" method won't it overload driver memeory on a cluster?

Comment: So, a spark `DF` column having just one row having list of lists, right?

Comment: yes a spark DF . also if possible don't use .collect

Comment: Yes, Exactly @cph_sto

Answer (score 0):

DataFrames, same as other distributed data structures, are not iterable  and by only using dedicated higher order function and / or SQL methods can be accessed

Suppose your Dataframe is DF1 and Output is DF2

You need something like :

```
values = [(['Justin', 'Lee'],), (['Chatbots', 'were'],), (['Our', 'hopes', 'were'],),
          (['And', 'why', 'wouldn'],), (['At', 'the', 'Mobile'],)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(values, ['author', ])
df.agg(F.collect_list('author').alias('author')).show(truncate=False)
```

Upvote if works

Comment: AssertionError: col should be Column
Throws this error

Comment: OP is asking not to collect to the driver, which you are doing by putting it all in `list1`.